# Issue in displaying result of selected item in Listpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I am writing an application by using sharedPreference and i want to `display the selected item of list` in display.

I am using the follwing code:

```
 refresh.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                    Object newValue) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "list preference:"+newValue.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                refresh.setSummary(refresh.getEntry());
                return true;
            }
        });
```

but the issue is, i can't display the current selected item of list. Instead of this, i am receiving the previous selected item of list.

I don't know that whether the one which i am using, is correct.

Is there any other way to display it?

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `preference.getSummary()` instead of `newValue.toString()`

```
refresh.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "list preference:"+preferences.getString("preference_key"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            refresh.setSummary(preferences.getString("preference_key"));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: there is no getString method in preferences? is it preferences or preference? but both not having getString method.

Comment: By preferences, I point to the `SharedPreference` object and not the `Preference` object.